# How to disable scrolling for CalendarView - Android Dev

Tags: java, android, calendarview

I am currently refreshing my android developement skills and came across the **CalendarView** component. I wanted to **disable the scrolling** of the calendar and instead enable the arrows to browse through the calendar.

**What I want to know is the following:**
How can I disable the scrolling from the CalendarView? And why does Android Studio show me the arrow browse-version in the Designer-Mode but compiles and runs the scroll-version of the calendar?

I am running an Android VM, a "Galaxy Nexus" with API 22. I also posted the "build.gradle" further below.

### **What Android shows me/What I want:**

[image]

### **What Android Studio compiles & runs:**

### [image]

---

### **Here some code:**

**// activity_main.java:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">

        <CalendarView
            android:id="@+id/calendarView4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:isScrollContainer="false" />
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**// build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.kalender003_emptyactivity"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to **Vaibhav Goyal** i came across the solution.

The **API level** I used was to low (API 22, Android 5.1). Changing that to **API 23** (Android 6.0) solved my problem. Now it shows me the CalendarView with arrow-navigation instead of the scroll version!

Answer (score 1):

Use MaterialComponents Theme, it will most probably solve the issue.

In your values/themes file replace the parent them with this,

```
parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar"
```

If you don't want Action Bar then ,

```
parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar"
```

And if you only want to show Light Coloured Calendar view regardless of Devices's theme use,

```
parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar"
```

Comment: Unfortunately id didn't solved my problem. It still shows me the scrollable CalendarView. Do i have to do other steps maybe?

Comment: I have implementated the same using the exact code like you, and in my case it's working fine. Which device are you using to test? Maybe that's a device specific problem.

Comment: Thank you for reproducing. I have updated my post and added the **build.gradle** file. I am running a Android-Device VM, a "Galaxy Nexus" with API 22. Could it be because of this??

Comment: Thanks to you I now know that the reason was the low API level. I have tried it with API 23 (Android 6.0) and now it shows me the desired CalendarView with arrow navigation!

Comment: Welcome OlsonLong.

Answer (score -1):

```
yourCalenenderId.addOnItemTouchListener(object : RecyclerView.SimpleOnItemTouchListener() {
        override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(rv: RecyclerView, e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
            return if (e.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                true
            } else {
                super.onInterceptTouchEvent(rv, e)
            }
        }
    })
```